# ¿Hasta qué punto es SOLID un controlador de Spring con varios end points?

Tags: spring

Es una pregunta que me ronda la cabeza hace tiempo. Si nos ceñimos a la definición de los principios, un controlador tendría mas de una responsabilidad si el controlador tiene varios endpoints y más de un motivo para cambiar, ¿qué opináis?

Lo mismo pasa con un servicio, si tengo un servicio ClientsService y en el atiendo todas las necesidades del ClientsController, no estoy cumpliendo con los principios, ¿no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me temo que es un tema muy subjetivo. He visto ambos enfoques implementados:

- Una clase *Controller* para cada llamada dentro de un paquete `clients`:

  ```
  com.empresa.app.rest.clients.CreateClientController
  com.empresa.app.rest.clients.UpdateClientController
  com.empresa.app.rest.clients.ListClientsController
  ...
  ```
- Una clase con todos los métodos relativos a una ruta base común:

  ```
  @RestController
  @RequestMapping("/clients")
  public class ClienController {

    @GetMapping("")
    List<Clients> getAll() {...

    @PostMapping("")
    Client createClient(@RequestBody Client c) { ...

    @GetMapping("{clientId}"}
    Client getClientById(@PathVariable("clientId") Integer id) { ...

    ...
  }
  ```

Y personalmente uso una mezcla de ambas cosas:

- Puedes entender que un Controller tiene una responsabilidad: gestionar clientes
- Puedes entender que esa responsiblidad es demasiado grande y es mejor usar la estrategia *divide y vencerás* y separar los GET (listar clientes, ver los detalles de un único cliente, del POST (crear un cliente suele ser algo complejo, con muchas comprobaciones y a menudo grabar en varias tablas) y del PUT (más de lo mismo, complejo)
- Puedes crear una clase para cada método (personalmente no lo hago porque prefiero una clase de 100 líneas que dos de 60, por el código *boiler plate*)

Por tanto es un caso de interpretación de qué es una responsabilidad y cuándo debe considerarse dividirla en varias.